# Google Spreadsheet, IF value is greater than 2 take the value next to it, over a range. Then sum

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So right now my formula is

```
=SUM(IF(F15>=2, G15, 0), IF(F16>=2, G16, 0), IF(F17>=2, G17, 0), IF(F18>=2, G18, 0))
```

But I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this for a range as this should go to F29|G29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`, making the first range a conditional one that will result to true/false (0/1), which will multiply by it's column below, if it's false will return 0, if it's true, will return (1*column G), as so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(F15:F29>=2;G15:G29)
```

Comment: @SuperWig if you this answer was well formated and explained, vote it up on the up arrow just over the "0", if this solved you issue mark it as answered in the checkmark just below the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, what you are looking for is the [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) function

To replicate what you are trying to do in the range provided in your question, you would need to use the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(F15:F29,">=2",G15:G29)
```

To use [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en) in Google Sheets as per [Kriggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941639/kriggs) answer, the parameters must be separated by a comma (`,`) not semi-colon(`;`) as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(F15:F29>=2,G15:G29)
```

Comment: The comma/semi-colon is a location based settings.